# pyzmq error when loading the module

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to install pyzmq to get ipython wotking in qtconsole mode.

I have installed zeromq in the default location (/usr/local). Both the dynamic lib and the header are at the correct position.

The I cloned the git repo for pyzmq and run the configuration command :

```
[root@XXXXX pyzmq]# python setup.py configure --zmq=/usr/local
running configure
************************************************
Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/core -Izmq/devices -c detect/vers.c -o detect/vers.o
gcc -pthread detect/vers.o -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -lzmq -o detect/vers
ZMQ version detected: 2.2.0
************************************************
```

So far so good. Then I run the installation command :

```
[root@XXXXXX pyzmq]# python setup.py install
 running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
************************************************
Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/core -Izmq/devices -c detect/vers.c -o detect/vers.o
gcc -pthread detect/vers.o -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -lzmq -o detect/vers
    ZMQ version detected: 2.2.0
************************************************
skipping 'zmq/core/_poll.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/_version.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/constants.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/context.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/device.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/error.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/message.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/socket.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/core/stopwatch.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/utils/initthreads.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/utils/rebuffer.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'zmq/devices/monitoredqueue.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-2.2dev-py2.7.egg-info
```

Then I try to load the module in python :

```
>>> import zmq
```

This works (after having added the --inplace in the setup.py command)

But when I start ipython qtconsole I get this error (after several other lines):

```
import zmq
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from zmq import core, devices
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from zmq.core import (constants, error, message, context,
  File "message.pxd", line 39, in init zmq.core.poll (zmq/core/poll.c:2950)
ValueError: zmq.core.message.Message has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Any idea where this could come from ?

Answer (score 0):

@akira - It could be that you checkout the tag (v2.2.0) from their github repository. I saw the same issue by doing so. Then I downloaded the tar.gz for v2.2.0 from pypi and it worked fine.